# where `form.as_p`in django templates come from?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I have a generic view and a form template.
my view is:

```
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_new.html"
    fields = "__all__"
```

and my form template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>New Post</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

now my question is about **form.as_p** or specifically **form**.
**Where did that come from?**

help me please. thanks a lot

Comment: It comes from the `render()` call: `render(request, 'foo.html', {'form': form})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`.as_p()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#as-p) is a method on a `Form`. It produces a [**`SafeText`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.SafeText) that contains HTML code to be included in the template.

The fact that it is `SafeText` is important, since the Django render engine will otherwise "escape" it: without using `SafeText`, it would replace `<` with `&lt;`; `>` with `&gt;`, etc. Unless of course you wrap it in a `SafeText` object yourself, for example through the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe).

We can for example define a form [like in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data):

> ```
> class OptionalPersonForm(forms.Form):
>     first_name = forms.CharField()
>     last_name = forms.CharField()
>     nick_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
> ```

If we then construct a form object, we can call the `.as_p()` method:

```
>>> OptionalPersonForm().as_p()
'<p><label for="id_first_name">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="first_name" required id="id_first_name"></p>\n<p><label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="last_name" required id="id_last_name"></p>\n<p><label for="id_nick_name">Nick name:</label> <input type="text" name="nick_name" id="id_nick_name"></p>'
>>> type(OptionalPersonForm().as_p())
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
```

Django forms have three popular rendering methods: `.as_p`, [**`.as_table()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#as-table) and [**`.as_ul()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#as-ul). The difference is that these render the HTML slightly differently: as paragraphs,  a table or unordered HTML list.