# Where does the value 'form' in 'form.as_p' in Django template come from?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I know this question was asked before, but the accepted answer does not really answer the question:
[where `form.as_p`in django templates come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444339/where-form-as-pin-django-templates-come-from)

In Django doc:

Example myapp/views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```

Example myapp/author_form.html:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

The question is, where does the template get the 'form' context from, since we did not explicitly define a render() function inside the AuthorCreate class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

`CreateView` inherits the `get` method from `ProcessFormView` class and the `get_context_data` method from the `FormMixin` class.

As you can see in the code, the `get` method returns an expression that calls `get_context_data`.

```
class ProcessFormView(View):
    """Render a form on GET and processes it on POST."""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Handle GET requests: instantiate a blank version of the form."""
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

In turn, `get_context_data` adds a keyword argument with key `form` if it is not already present in `**kwargs`:

```
class FormMixin(ContextMixin):
...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Insert the form into the context dict."""
        if 'form' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

So `CreateView` renders a Response with a context that has a 'form' key and a value ponting to the `ModelForm`.